# Carousel in MDBootstrap Pro does not display properly

Tags: carousel, bootstrap-5, mdbootstrap

I am working with the latest edition of MDB Pro and can't get a simple carousel example to work.  I want to have a 3-image slider that is responsive and full-width to the screen, and I copied and pasted sample code that (theoretically) should work, but it doesn't.  It displays the first image, but not the other three.  Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <title>MyMooseBox.com - <%=Page.Title %></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="content/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mdb.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/css/all.min.css" />

    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/js/all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.13.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-mdb-toggle="collapse"
                data-mdb-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <a class="navbar-brand mt-2 mt-lg-0" href="#">
                    <img src="img/ps_nameonly.png" height="40" alt="MDB Logo" loading="lazy" />
                </a>
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Team</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <a class="link-secondary me-3" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="link-secondary me-3 dropdown-toggle hidden-arrow" href="#"
                        id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-mdb-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
                        <span class="badge rounded-pill badge-notification bg-danger">1</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Some news</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another news</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle d-flex align-items-center hidden-arrow" href="#"
                        id="navbarDropdownMenuAvatar" role="button" data-mdb-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/new/avatars/2.webp"
                            lass="rounded-circle" height="25" alt="Black and White Portrait of a Man" loading="lazy" />
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end"
                        aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuAvatar">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My profile</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cpMain" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong?  Thanks for the help!